# document size settings, size and resolution are not working properly

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Using Photoshop, when I change the document size from to 72.25cm x 54.19cm at 72ppi to 12cm x 9cm the resolution jumps to 433.493ppi.

How can I stop Photoshop from doing this?

Comment: Is the image for print or screen?

Comment: The ppi flag is being "altered" so as to avoid changing the exact pixel dimensions. The size is derived from the pixels divided by the ppi; the ppi is derived from the pixels and the specified inches. In both cases the pixels remain fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Immediate solution, check the "Resample Image" option in the Image size dialog window.

**More importantly** you need to explain the **final output** of the image. For print, you may want the 433ppi. You haven't provided enough detail in your question to thoroughly answer. ***You can edit your question to provide these types of detail.***